# When I run this code, it gives None instead of the 'Python' getting appended to the List. Why is that so?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code, it gives None instead of the 'Python' getting appended to the List. Why is that so?

```
input_tuple = ('Monty Python', 'British', 1969)  
input_list = list(input_tuple)  
print(input_list)  
input_list_1 = input_list.append('Python')  
print(input_list_1)
```

Comment: You are calling an object function here (right side of =): `input_list_1 = input_list.append('Python')`. No value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending line:

```
input_list_1 = input_list.append('Python')
```

The `append()` method updates the list in place. It returns no value (i.e. it returns `None`). Since you are assigning the return value of `append()` to `input_list_1`, the printed value is expected to be "None".

Answer (score 0):

`array.append()` changes the array passed directly instead of returning the changed array. To give an example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.append(4)
print(array)
```

Outputs `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Therefore, your code should be:

```
input_tuple = ('Monty Python', 'British', 1969)
input_list = list(input_tuple)
print(input_list)
input_list.append('Python')
print(input_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

`input_list_1` returns `None` because you are appending into `input_list`. At this point `input_list_1` stores returned value of append operation - which is `None`. To print updated list you should print the `input_list`.

Answer (score -1):

input_list is list object and append is a list object method which is direct changes in list instant of return changes.that's why none object is returned and input_list_1 does not print anything.